# Mysql Get lastest value and use it on insert statement

Tags: mysql, insert

I have insert query as below.

```
 INSERT INTO services 
 ( date
 , company_id
 , company
 , vehicle
 , debt
 , balance
 , comments)
 VALUES 
 ( :date
 , :company_id
 , :company
 , :vehicle
 , :debt
 , :last_balance
 , :comments)
```

i use another query to get latest balance like below

```
$last_balance= App\Db::i()->fetch('
SELECT balance 
  FROM services 
 WHERE company_id = '. $id . ' 
 ORDER    
    BY id DESC');
```

It works but i want to do better way. Any ideas?

Comment: I presume https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php would be what you'd use. This looks like PHP using PDO (although `App\Db::i()` might be some framework?). Likely your `$id` should be being bound as well.

Comment: I am using my simple framework. I am just trying to make it simple if possible.

Comment: If `App\Db` is a PDO connection use the `lastinsertid` function.

Comment: Why are you using placeholders in one query and then using SQL injection in the other? Use placeholders *every time* you can.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use :last_balance from you query? I'm pretty sure you are bind this variable from php to mysql somewhere below. Another way is to assign mysql variable:

```
INSERT INTO services (date,company_id,company,vehicle,debt,balance,comments)
SELECT :date, :company_id, :company, :vehicle, :debt, @lb:= :last_balance, :comments
```

and select it in another query:

```
$last_balance= App\Db::i()->fetch('SELECT @lb:');
```

Comment: Yes it's possible to workout bind values from somewhere outside. My goal is make it all in one query.